# Protractor change size of element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I can give the size of the element with the `getSize` method but I can't figure how to change the `height` (for instance) of that element.

Just to provide some more context I want to test if the end user can resize a `textarea` element. Should I just set the height or is their a way to simulate user interaction with the element.

Thanks in advance

**Solution**
My implementation looks like this:

```
myElement.getSize().then(function(result){ 
    browser.driver.actions()
      .mouseMove(inputElement, {x: result.width-1, y: result.height-1})
      .mouseDown()
      .mouseMove(inputElement, {y: newHeight })
      .mouseUp()
      .perform()
});
```

This allows me simulate user interaction resizing the textarea element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `browser.executeScript()` to modify height of an element in Protractor.Something like below should work for you

```
 browser.executeScript('$("div").height(500)').then(function(){
        $("div").getSize().then(function(eleSize){
            console.log('element size: '+eleSize);
            expect(eleSize.height).toEqual(500);
        });
    })
```

You can professionalize this passing the element as an argument to `browser.executeScript()`

And if you really want to simulate end-user action of clicking & dragging the text box boundaries, yes its possible.The Key is to create a [action sequence](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/javascript/module/selenium-webdriver/lib/actions_exports_ActionSequence.html) and  [browser.action()](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.actions)can be leveraged

In case you are interested , I have tried something similar - [drawing a signature using protractor](https://testautomation-aditya.com/2016/09/30/how-to-automate-signature-action-in-seleniumprotractor/)

Comment: I don't think this will work, after `browser.executeScript` you are now in the browser context, so `getSize()` will not be a function available to you.  Also your `console.log` will be logged to the browser, not your terminal.

Comment: @Gunderson Sorry I didn't get you, `Browser` is in global scope and getSize() is indeed available. I just checked it and 'console.log' is printing to console and not `browser-console`. We are just handling the promise of `browser.executeScript`

Comment: @AdityaReddy thanks for the help. I've updated the question with the solution.

Comment: @AdityaReddy Ah sorry, I didn't read close enough.  Didn't see you closed off `executeScript()` in the first line.

Comment: You don't want to use `.executeScript()` if you are trying to simulate a user's action.